# delete a row in a table using radio button in java

Tags: java, jsp, postgresql-9.2

Here I have created a table `TempDB` and I have to insert its value to another table `UserDB` if the values in the `TempDB` is correct, otherwise I have to delete that row and there is an extra column in `User_db` which must be a sequence.

This is the definition of the `Temp_db`:

```
CREATE TABLE "tempDB"(name character varying(20) NOT NULL,email character varying(20), house_no numeric, street_name character varying,ward_no numeric,  phone_no numeric,area numeric, floor numeric, c_area numeric,  CONSTRAINT "tempDB_pkey" PRIMARY KEY (email))WITH ( OIDS=FALSE);
```

This is the definition of `User_db`:

```
CREATE TABLE "UserDB"( name character varying(20) NOT NULL,  accession_no character varying NOT NULL,  email character varying(20),  house_no numeric,  street_name character varying,  ward_no numeric,  phone_no numeric,  area numeric,  floor numeric,  c_area numeric,  CONSTRAINT "UserDB_pkey" PRIMARY KEY (accession_no))WITH (  OIDS=FALSE);
```

Here accession_no should be a sequence.
now in a jsp page i am viewing the tempDB and there is 2 radio buttons on each row named confirmed and rejected.

```
try
            {
                Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
                Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASS); 
                Statement st=conn.createStatement();
                ResultSet r=st.executeQuery("SELECT * from tempDB");
                int i=1;
                String radio="radio"+i;
        %>
    <form name="request" action="http://localhost:8080/PTMS/SaveData" id="form1" method="post">
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Email ID</th>
                                <th>House no.</th>
                                <th>Street name</th>
                                <th>Ward no.</th>
                                <th>Phone no.</th>
                                <th>Total area</th>
                                <th>No. of floors</th>
                                <th>Commercial area</th>
                                <th>Amount of tax</th>
                                <th>Operation</th>
                            </tr>
                            <% while(r.next()) 
                            {                       
                            %>
                            <tr>
                                <td><%= r.getString(1) %></td>
                                <td><%= r.getString(2) %></td>
                                <td><%= r.getString(3) %></td>
                                <td><%= r.getString(4) %></td>
                                <td><%= r.getString(5) %></td>
                                <td><%= r.getString(6) %></td>
                                <td><%= r.getString(7) %></td>
                                <td><%= r.getString(8) %></td>
                                <td><%= r.getString(9) %></td>
                                <td><%= r.getString(10) %></td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="radio" name="radio" value="Confirmed">
                                    <input type="radio" name="radio" value="Rejected">
                                </td>
                            <%
                            i++;
                            }           
                             %>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                    </form>
```

now if confirmed radio button is selected then the value will be stored in the `UserDB` and if rejected button is selected then the row will be deleted from `Temp_DB`.
Please provide the java code to perform this operation.

Comment: Java code in JSP is a bad idea.

Comment: Even worse: SQL statements in a JSP are a **really** bad idea.